# How to declare multiple variable useRef with a loop? Is that possible

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to clean up the code to be `DRY` from my senior.

Initially my logic and code is already working but senior want me to improve my code.

My code is something like this

```
const firstTextInputRef = useRef(null);
const secondTextInputRef = useRef(null);
const thirdTextInputRef = useRef(null);
const fourthTextInputRef = useRef(null);
const fifthTextInputRef = useRef(null);
const sixthTextInputRef = useRef(null);

const onOtpKeyPress = index => {
    return ({nativeEvent: {key: value}}) => {
        // auto focus to previous InputText if value is blank and existing value is also blank
        if (value === 'Backspace' && otpArray[index] === '') {
            if (index === 1) {
                firstTextInputRef.current.focus();
            } else if (index === 2) {
                secondTextInputRef.current.focus();
            } else if (index === 3) {
                thirdTextInputRef.current.focus();
            } else if (index === 4) {
                fourthTextInputRef.current.focus();
            } else if (index === 5) {
                fifthTextInputRef.current.focus();
            }
        }
    };
};
```

What I am doing now is I am listening to keypress and change the focus of the keyboard from 1 input to another.

What he want me to do is I need to declare the ref inside a loop and improve the `if else` statement

This snippet is what he suggest.

```
let otpTextInputs = [];
for(let i = 0; ;i!=5;i++) {
 // put new ref into the array
}
```

I already tried multiple way and spend more that 2 hours on it and I still don't know how to do it. Can anyone suggest an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a `useEffect` that runs when you first initialize your component that generates the inputs programmatically and sets their `ref`. That way you can set up a state where you can store all the refs and then access them.

Here is a [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-star-b10mr?file=/src/App.js) with the proposed solution.